# Fourier transform of $\frac{e^{2ix}}{1+x^2}+3p_2(x-1)$

Tags: integration, analysis, fourier-transform

$$f(x)=\frac{e^{2ix}}{1+x^2}+3p_2(x-1)$$

$$p_2(x)=\begin{cases} 1 \qquad x \in [-1,1] \\ 0 \qquad x  \notin [-1,1]    \end{cases}$$

$$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}  p_2(x) \  e^{-i\omega x} \ dx=2 \ \frac{\sin(\omega )}{\omega} $$

So:
$$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} 3 p_2(x-1) \  e^{-i\omega x} \ dx=6 \ \frac{\sin(\omega )}{\omega} \ e^{-i \omega }$$

$$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \frac{e^{2ix}}{1+x^2} \  e^{-i\omega x} \ dx$$

Using Residue theorem:

$$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \frac{e^{2ix}}{1+x^2} \  e^{-i\omega x} \ dx=2\pi i \ \ \lim_{x\rightarrow i} \ \frac{e^{-i\omega x+2ix}}{x+i}=2 \pi i \ \ \frac{e^\omega \ e^{-2}}{2i}=\pi \ e^\omega \ e^{-2} $$

$$F(\omega)=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} f(x) \  e^{-i\omega x} \ dx=\pi \ e^\omega \ e^{-2}+6 \ \frac{\sin(\omega )}{\omega} \ e^{-i \omega }$$

Is it correct?

Which are the conditions I have to verify to establish if $F$ inverse Fourier transform is possible?

Should I verify $F \in L^1(\mathbb{R})$?

Thanks!

Comment: if $\int_{\mathbb{R}}\tilde{f}(\omega)d\omega$ exists the inverse FT is well defined. So yes, you are right

Comment: since $||f(x)||_1\geq ||f(x)||_p$ any other norm also does the job